# Values getting stored twice in the database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am not considering SQL injections as of now will do it once i am done with this problem

The problem i have is when i am trying to insert data on the server through AsyncTask the values are inserted twice. I tried using counter to check whether the AsyncTask is called twice or not but the value is " 1 ".

// This is My Class file

```
public class Add extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

String picturePath;
final String fontPath1 = "fonts/COPRGTB.TTF";
    int cnt=0;
// --------------------------------------------
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
String SD_CARD_IMAGE_PATH = null;
Bitmap thumbnail = null;
private static final int OG = 4; 
Cursor cursor;
private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
Uri u;
// int z=0;
String z = null;
byte b[];
String largeImagePath = "";
Uri uriLargeImage;
Uri uriThumbnailImage;
Cursor myCursor, cursor1;
int flagg = 0;

// --------------------------------------------
String FILENAME = "http://animsinc.com/test.php";
// NAME = "http://animsinc.com/upload_image.php";
private CarHelper dbcarhelper = null;
private Cursor ourCursor, cur;
String fuel[] = new String[] { "Select Any", "Petrol", "Diesel", "CNG" };
String owner[] = new String[] { "Select Any", "1 Owner", "2 Owners",
        "3 Owners", "4 Owners" };
String curloc[] = new String[] { "Select Any", "Mumbai", "Pune", "Thane",
        "Delhi" };

Button img, bt, af;
ImageView imgview;
PopupWindow popUp;
EditText et1, et2, et4, et5, et6;
String str1, str2, str4, str5, str6, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, c1, s, i;
Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5, sp6, sp7;
CheckBox cb;
private EditText mDateDisplay;
public static String id = null;
private EditText mDateDisplayone;
private EditText mDateDisplaytwo;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_ONE = 2;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_TWO = 3;
String mm = "";
int flag = 0;

String bal;

public void setvalues(String xID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    id = xID;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_car);

    Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath1);

    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView t7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    TextView t8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    TextView t9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TextView t10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TextView t11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    TextView t12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    t1.setTypeface(tf1);
    t2.setTypeface(tf1);
    t3.setTypeface(tf1);
    t4.setTypeface(tf1);
    t5.setTypeface(tf1);
    t6.setTypeface(tf1);
    t7.setTypeface(tf1);
    t8.setTypeface(tf1);
    t9.setTypeface(tf1);
    t10.setTypeface(tf1);
    t11.setTypeface(tf1);
    t12.setTypeface(tf1);
    img = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // --------------------------------
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        Bitmap carpic;
        String B1 = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
        // Toast.makeText(this, "SavedYeah"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = OG;

        carpic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((B1), opts);
        System.gc();
        if (carpic != null) {

            imageCam(carpic);
        }

    }

    // --------------------------------
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    imgview = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnClickListener(click_img);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bal=" + bal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    // sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter spnfuel = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spin_adptr, fuel);

    spnfuel.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
    sp4.setAdapter(spnfuel);
    // sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter spncurloc = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spin_adptr,
            curloc);

    spncurloc.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
    sp5.setAdapter(spncurloc);
    // sp5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter spnowner = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spin_adptr,
            owner);

    spnowner.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
    sp6.setAdapter(spnowner);
    // sp6.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter spnreg = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spin_adptr,
            curloc);

    spnreg.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
    sp7.setAdapter(spnreg);

    af = (Button) findViewById(R.id.img);
    //af.setTypeface(tf1);
    af.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 1;

            if ((et1.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et2.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et4.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et5.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et6.getText().length() == 0)) {

            } else {

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    c1 = cb.getText().toString();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),     "c=" +
                    // c,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    c1 = "Not Negotiable";
                }

                // spinner values
                s1 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s3 = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s4 = sp4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s5 = sp5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s6 = sp6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s7 = sp7.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // edittext values
                str1 = et1.getText().toString();
                str2 = et2.getText().toString();
                str4 = et4.getText().toString();
                str5 = et5.getText().toString();
                str6 = et6.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + str1 + str2
                                + str4 + str5 + str6 + c1,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });

    dbcarhelper = new CarHelper(this);
    dbcarhelper.createDatabase();
    dbcarhelper.openDataBase();

    if (s != null) {
        startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s ,
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dbcarhelper.disp();
    CarHelper h = new CarHelper(getApplicationContext());

    List<String> lab = h.getAllLab();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spin_adptr, lab);

    dataAdap.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
    sp1.setAdapter(dataAdap);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    if (i != null) {
        startManagingCursor(cur);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i ,
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    //cb.setTypeface(tf1);

    Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    //pickDate.setTypeface(tf1);

    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    updateDisplay();

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //bt.setTypeface(tf1);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((et1.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et2.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et4.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et5.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (et6.getText().length() == 0)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    c1 = cb.getText().toString();
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "c=" +
                    // c,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    c1 = "Not Negotiable";
                }

                // spinner values
                s1 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s3 = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s4 = sp4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s5 = sp5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s6 = sp6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s7 = sp7.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // edittext values
                str1 = et1.getText().toString();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "km=" +
                // str1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str2 = et2.getText().toString();
                str4 = et4.getText().toString();
                str5 = et5.getText().toString();
                str6 = et6.getText().toString();

                startDownload();

                et1.setText("");
                et2.setText("");
                et4.setText("");
                et5.setText("");
                et6.setText("");

                sp1.setSelection(0);
                sp2.setSelection(0);
                sp3.setSelection(0);
                sp4.setSelection(0);
                sp5.setSelection(0);
                sp6.setSelection(0);
                sp7.setSelection(0);

            }
        }
    });

}

public void imageCam(Bitmap thumbnail) {

    flag = 1;

    Bitmap photo = thumbnail;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
    b = bos.toByteArray();
    bal = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String BX1 = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if (BX1.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung") && flagg == 0) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device man"+BX1,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(),
                photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    }

    // Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 400, false);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);

}

private void startDownload() {

    new AddTask().execute(FILENAME);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}

private View.OnClickListener click_img = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openNewGameDialog();

    }
};

String[] B = { "Camera", "Gallery" };

private void openNewGameDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(B,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        String BX1 = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

                        if (BX1.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")) {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "Device man"+BX1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent,
                                    CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        } else {
                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                    CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }

                    else if (i == 1) {
                        // Intent in = new
                        // Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        // startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                    }

                }
            }).show();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        flagg = 0;
        // Describe the columns you'd like to have returned. Selecting from
        // the Thumbnails location gives you both the Thumbnail Image ID, as
        // well as the original image ID
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select
                                                                        // only
                                                                        // mini's
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

        String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";

        // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning ALL
        // images, and just taking the latest one. There is a better way to
        // narrow this down I think with a WHERE clause which is currently
        // the selection variable
        myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, null, sort);

        long imageId = 0l;
        long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
        String thumbnailPath = "";

        try {

            myCursor.moveToFirst();
            imageId = myCursor
                    .getLong(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
            thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                    .getLong(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
            thumbnailPath = myCursor
                    .getString(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
        } finally {
            // myCursor.close();
        }

        // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image

        String[] largeFileProjection = {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

        String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
        myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
        largeImagePath = "";

        try {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();

            // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
            // image.
            largeImagePath = myCursor
                    .getString(myCursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
        } finally {

            // myCursor.close();
        }
        // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They give you a
        // handle to the actual images
        uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                String.valueOf(imageId));
        uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

        // I've left out the remaining code, as all I do is assign the URI's
        // to my own objects anyways...
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+largeImagePath,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage,
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (largeImagePath != null) {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "LARGE YES"+largeImagePath,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = OG;
            // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((largeImagePath), opts);
            System.gc();
            if (thumbnail != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Try Without Saved Instance",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageCam(thumbnail);
            }

        }
        if (uriLargeImage != null) {

            // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriLargeImage,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        if (uriThumbnailImage != null) {

            // Toast.makeText(this, ""+uriThumbnailImage,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    if (requestCode == 1337 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        flagg = 0;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        // if (extras!=null){
        if (extras.keySet().contains("data")) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // options.inSampleSize = 1;
            // options.inPurgeable = true;
            // options.inInputShareable = true;
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            // image(thumbnail);
            if (thumbnail != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "YES Thumbnail",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // options.inSampleSize = 1;
                // options.inPurgeable = true;
                // options.inInputShareable = true;
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageCam(thumbnail);
            }

        } else {

            Uri imageURI = getIntent().getData();
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageview.setImageURI(imageURI);

            if (imageURI != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "YES Image Uri",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            // Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        flagg = 1;

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn,
                null, null, null);
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor1.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
        // cursor.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = OG;
        // thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((picturePath), opts);
        System.gc();
        if (thumbnail != null) {
            imageCam(thumbnail);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a different picture",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    else {
        // imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbtb);
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View position, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    int id = parent.getId();

    switch (id) {
    case R.id.spinner1:

        String b = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (b != null) {
            dbcarhelper.m_pop(b);
        }

        CarHelper ch = new CarHelper(getApplicationContext());

        List<String> lables = ch.getAllLabels();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spin_adptr, lables);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);

        sp2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        break;

    case R.id.spinner2:
        String a = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (a != null) {
            dbcarhelper.v_pop(a);
        }

        CarHelper c = new CarHelper(getApplicationContext());

        List<String> lable = c.getAllLabel();

        ArrayAdapter<String> dAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spin_adptr, lable);

        dAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_drop);
        sp3.setAdapter(dAdapter);
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_ONE:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListenerone, mYear,
                mMonth, mDay);

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TWO:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListenertwo, mYear,
                mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenertwo = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplaytwo();

    }
};

protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        break;

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_ONE:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        break;

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID_TWO:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        break;
    }
}

private void updateDisplaytwo() {

    int month = mMonth + 1;

    if (month == 1) {
        mm = "Jan";
    } else if (month == 2) {
        mm = "Feb";
    } else if (month == 3) {
        mm = "Mar";
    } else if (month == 4) {
        mm = "Apr";
    } else if (month == 5) {
        mm = "May";
    } else if (month == 6) {
        mm = "Jun";
    }

    else if (month == 7) {
        mm = "Jul";
    } else if (month == 8) {
        mm = "Aug";
    } else if (month == 9) {
        mm = "Sep";
    } else if (month == 10) {
        mm = "Oct";
    }

    else if (month == 11) {
        mm = "Nov";
    }

    else if (month == 12) {
        mm = "Dec";
    }

    mDateDisplaytwo.setText(new StringBuilder()

    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            // .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mm).append("-")

            .append(mYear).append(""));
}

private void updateDisplay() {

    int month = mMonth + 1;

    if (month == 1) {
        mm = "Jan";
    } else if (month == 2) {
        mm = "Feb";
    } else if (month == 3) {
        mm = "Mar";
    } else if (month == 4) {
        mm = "Apr";
    } else if (month == 5) {
        mm = "May";
    } else if (month == 6) {
        mm = "Jun";
    }

    else if (month == 7) {
        mm = "Jul";
    } else if (month == 8) {
        mm = "Aug";
    } else if (month == 9) {
        mm = "Sep";
    } else if (month == 10) {
        mm = "Oct";
    }

    else if (month == 11) {
        mm = "Nov";
    }

    else if (month == 12) {
        mm = "Dec";
    }

    et5.setText(new StringBuilder()

    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            // .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mm).append("-")

            .append(mYear).append(""));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();

    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerone = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplayone();

    }
};

private void updateDisplayone() {

    int month = mMonth + 1;

    if (month == 1) {
        mm = "Jan";
    } else if (month == 2) {
        mm = "Feb";
    } else if (month == 3) {
        mm = "Mar";
    } else if (month == 4) {
        mm = "Apr";
    } else if (month == 5) {
        mm = "May";
    } else if (month == 6) {
        mm = "Jun";
    }

    else if (month == 7) {
        mm = "Jul";
    } else if (month == 8) {
        mm = "Aug";
    } else if (month == 9) {
        mm = "Sep";
    } else if (month == 10) {
        mm = "Oct";
    }

    else if (month == 11) {
        mm = "Nov";
    }

    else if (month == 12) {
        mm = "Dec";
    }

    mDateDisplayone.setText(new StringBuilder()

    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            // .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mm).append("-")

            .append(mYear).append(""));
}

public class AddTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(Add.this, "Result=" + result + "cnt= " + cnt, 1000).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String is = null;

        String trans = "No", ac = "No", lockk = "No", roof = "No", win = "No", seat = "No", stearing = "No", player = "No", wheel = "No", sys = "No", dr = "No";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://animsinc.com/test.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    30);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Make", s1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Model", s2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Version", s3));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FuelType", s4));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kilo", str1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Price", str2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Reg", s7));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Color", str4));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mdate", str5));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Desc", str6));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Loc", s5));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Owners", s6));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Negot", c1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Trans", trans));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Drive", dr));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lockk", lockk));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AC", ac));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Window", win));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("Stearing", stearing));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Seats", seat));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Player", player));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sunroof", roof));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sound", sys));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Wheel", wheel));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Seller_ID", id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Image", bal));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            cnt++;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return Integer.toString(cnt);

    }

}

}
```

//This is My PHP code test.php

```
<?php

require 'DbConnect.php';


$Make = $_POST["Make"];
$Model = $_POST["Model"];
$Version= $_POST["Version"];
$FuelType= $_POST["FuelType"];
$Kilo = $_POST["Kilo"];
$Price= $_POST["Price"];
$Reg= $_POST["Reg"];
$Color= $_POST["Color"];
$Mdate= $_POST["Mdate"];
$Desc= $_POST["Desc"];
$Loc= $_POST["Loc"];
$Owners = $_POST["Owners"];
$Negot= $_POST["Negot"]; 
$Trans= $_POST["Trans"];
$AC= $_POST["AC"];
$car_lockk= $_POST["Lockk"];
$Sunroof= $_POST["Sunroof"];
$Window= $_POST["Window"];
$Seat= $_POST["Seats"];
$Stearing= $_POST["Stearing"];
$Music= $_POST["Player"];
$Wheels= $_POST["Wheel"];
$Sound= $_POST["Sound"];
$Drive= $_POST["Drive"]; 
$IMG= $_POST["Image"];
$ID = $_POST["Seller_ID"]; 

$query2 = "INSERT INTO used_cars (make, model, version, color, manufacturing_date,   km_driven, fuel_type, expected_price, negotiable, registration_place, no_of_owners, description, current_location, transmission, ac, sunroof, window, seats, stearing, player, wheels, sound_system, drive, car_lockk, seller_id, img) VALUES ('$Make', '$Model', '$Version', '$Color', '$Mdate', '$Kilo', '$FuelType', '$Price', '$Negot', '$Reg', '$Owners', '$Desc', '$Loc', '$Trans', '$AC', '$Sunroof', '$Window', '$Seat', '$Stearing', '$Music', '$Wheels', '$Sound', '$Drive', '$car_lockk', '$ID', '$IMG')";

if((mysql_query($query2)))
{
    echo 'Success';
}else 
{
    echo 'Fail';
}

?>
```

// This is my DBConnect.php

```
<?php  


$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='abc';
$mysql_pass ='abc';



 if(!(@mysql_connect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)) ||!(@mysql_select_db('animsinc_CarList')) ){
die('Not Connected');

 }else{
//echo 'Connected.';
}


 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: if you are using eclipse IDE for developing your android app.. did you try debugging by adding breakpoint before and after your httpclient.execute().. see what data is passed how many times this line is called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to modify this code..

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            cnt++;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Use of httpclient.execute() twice might be the possible reason for the data being inserted twice.

Modify your code like this..

```
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
// httpclient.execute(httppost);
   cnt++;
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 0):

actually this type problem generally are browser issues which i faced too...
to fix it you can try to edit the .htaccess to prevent redirection to the index file when the browser is requesting 
and i guess your query is running fine for localy but the problem occurs when you deploy in server
to avoid this add this to your php file on starting,

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Mediapartners-Google') !== false) {
        exit();
    }
```

may this help you